# How to store the value in the object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I created an object and prompt the user for the values (which are divided by a comma) but how do I then display a certain value not the whole string?

Here is my code:

```
var obj = { 
 name: "",
 colors: [] };
 obj = prompt("Enter your name and favorite colors (separated by comma).”.split(‘,’));
alert(obj.name + "' favorite colors are " obj.colors);
```

Comment: you have a syntax error - just fix it

Comment: What is the expected output you want to have? It is not clear to me.

Comment: it is not clear, what to answer. a name and some colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.split()` you will get a array. And to use it you should do:

`obj[0]` and `obj[1]`, and hope for the user to add name first and not colour first...

If you don't want to use 2 different questionsa/promt you should do:

```
var obj = {};
var parts = prompt("Enter your name and favorite colors (separated by comma).").split(' ').join('').split(',');
obj.name = parts.shift();
console.log(parts)
obj.colors = parts;
alert(obj.name + "'s favorite colors are " + obj.colors.join(', '));
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/of5temug/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = { 
     name: "",
     colors: [] 
};
obj.name = prompt("Enter your name");
obj.colors = new Array(prompt("and favorite colors (separated by comma)."));
alert(obj.name + "'s favorite colors are " +obj.colors);
```

Comment: the colors are not split into array.